# Warning: Uglification failed. Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

Following is the error I am getting while uglifying -

Warning: Uglification failed. 
Unexpected token: name (type).

My code -

```
var buildRange = function(obj, type){
    for(var key in obj){
        andFilter.push({[type]:{[key]:obj[key]}});
    }
}
```

Code is breaking at this line -

```
andFilter.push({[type]:{[key]:obj[key]}});
```

Let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: Are you using Typescript or ES6 computed property polyfill? If not it will be invalid syntax

Comment: @PSL how could I check, as I am simply running the `grunt dist`  and getting the error..let me know how could I resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Tried to uglify your code and it also failed. The problem is with the brackets around property names. But the following can be uglified:

```
var buildRange = function(obj, type){
    for(var key in obj){
        andFilter.push({type:{key:obj[key]}});
    }
}
```